# I need to create this pattern with a for-while loop, but I guess my modulo instruction isn't quite right - how can I fix it?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I wanna create this illusion https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3FYh.jpg with a for-while loop but it doesn't really work.
I guess the modulo instruction is not quite right.. How can I fix it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int hCount = 128;
    int vCount = 32;
    int squrh = 4;
    int squrw = 16;

    StdDraw.setCanvasSize(512, 512);
    StdDraw.setXscale(0, 512);
    StdDraw.setYscale(0, 512);


    for (int h = 0; h < hCount; h++) {
        for (int v = 0; v < vCount; v++) {
            if ((h + v) % 2 == 1) StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLACK);
            else StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.WHITE);

            StdDraw.filledSquare(v * 512 / vCount, h * 512 / hCount, 512 / 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't really work"?

Comment: well, it works but only for the bottom left quarter, it looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/1QuWNMP